# Autofilling info from Google Forms to Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, google-forms

I'm a lawyer who is completely out of his element here. I've been researching and running tests on Google Script, however, I keep running into issues.

The goal:

Step 1 - Someone completes a Google Form (info includes name, number, etc.);

Step 2 - A NEW template spreadsheet is automatically generated in Google Drive;

Step 3 - The info from the Form is automatically populated within the new template spreadsheet.

Can anyone be a life saver and help me out? Or at least put me out of my misery haha.

Thanks so much in advance!

Update #1:

Based on a comment, here's where I'm at. Good news is that it accomplishes Step 1 and Step 2. Bad news is that I'm still figuring out Step 3, which is probably because I'm so new to this.

Anyways, here's what I have for Step 1 and 2:

```
function autoFillCaseInfofromIntake(e) {
  var Timestamp = e.values[0];
  var Source = e.values[1];
  var FullName = e.values[2];
  
  var templatefile = DriveApp.getFileById("I inserted ID here");

  var templatepopulatedfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("I inserted ID here");
  
  var copy = templatefile.makeCopy(FullName, templatepopulatedfolder);
  
  var sheet = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
 
  sheet.saveAndClose();
```

Again, sorry for the ignorance!

Update #2:

Big thanks to @arul selvan and @Iamblichus for helping to get me to where I needed to go!

Just in case someone needs the answer in the future:

```
function autoFillCaseInfofromIntake(e) {
  var Timestamp = e.values[0];
  var Source = e.values[1];
  var FullName = e.values[2];
  
  var templatefile = DriveApp.getFileById("I inserted ID here");

  var templatepopulatedfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("I inserted ID here");
  
  var copy = templatefile.makeCopy(FullName, templatepopulatedfolder);
  
  var newsheet = SpreasheetApp.openById(copy.getId());
  var sht1 = newsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//open the default sheet 1 or if you want you can rename the sheet or create a new sheet
  sht1.getRange("A1").setValue(Source); //populate any cell with value captured by the form
  sht1.getRange("B1").setValue(FullName);

}
```

Comment: It might help us if you shared a copy of your form.  And have you taken any steps to create a script to do what you want?  This site is intended to help you with specific problems, not to design solutions from scratch.  Here is how to ask a good question, that will increase the chance of people spending time to help you with your issue:      https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. The form is pretty basic (again -- name, number, etc.). And like I said in the OP, I've been trying to work it all out, however, I haven't made too much progress. I'll update the OP with where I'm at!

Comment: Do you have a spreadsheet? Why are you using `DocumentApp`? It should be `SpreadsheetApp` if you're working with a spreadsheet. Also, please clarify how you want data to be written to the sheet. Appended to the first empty line? And in what column, in what order, and which data? Would it be `Timestamp`, `Source` and `FullName` to columns A to C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cracked the difficult steps 1 and 2. The Step 3 is easy.

```
function autoFillCaseInfofromIntake(e) {
  var Timestamp = e.values[0];
  var Source = e.values[1];
  var FullName = e.values[2];
  
  var templatefile = DriveApp.getFileById("I inserted ID here");

  var templatepopulatedfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("I inserted ID here");
  
  var copy = templatefile.makeCopy(FullName, templatepopulatedfolder);
  
  var newsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(copy.getId());
  var sht1 = newsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//open the default sheet 1 or if you want you can rename the sheet or create a new sheet
  sht1.getRange("A1").setValue(Source); //populate any cell with value captured by the form
  sht1.getRange("B1").setValue(FullName);

}
```

#### Explanation:

- Get the desired sheet with [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename).
- Get the cells you want to change with [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation).
- Set the values of the cells with [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue).

I'm sure you figured out how to run the above script "On formSubmit"

Comment: Thanks so much! Looks like your answer got me to 98% of what I needed. The one tweak was incorporating @Iamblichus' advice to change DocumentApp to SpreadsheetApp and boom!

Comment: @JarrettStone if you find the answer useful, pl. consider upvoting it

Comment: Hi, I modified your answer a bit so in order to add explanation/reference about what the code is doing, apart from fixing the typo `DocumentApp` to `SpreadsheetApp`.

Comment: Also, both values could have been written at the same time with `sht1.getRange("A1:B1").setValues([[Source,FullName]]);`.

Comment: @arulselvan - apparently I don't have enough street cred to upvote at this point haha.

Comment: @Iamblichus - accepted the answer! You're the best!